# new to maven - how to do a "mvn3 clean install"

Tags: java, android, maven, junit

I have been going through [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBuildMaven/article.html) and I did the following:

- got maven installed
- created my environment variables
- created a new android project called "firstmaven"
- placed the pom.xml file in the C:\ADT\workspace\firstmaven folder,
  which I "think" is correct.. hope so.

the next step, is "run mvn3 clean install"  which I think will create the apk file...
but how? Do I open up my dos window, do a cd C:\ADT\workspace\firstmaven   ?

Comment: Did you try running "mvn3 clean install" from the command line in the folder C:\ADT\workspace\firstmaven?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Open command promt
- cd C:\ADT\workspace\firstmaven
- mvn clean install -e //prints the error trace in detail

[image]

Comment: that didnt work got message: C:\ADT\workspace\firstmaven>mvn 'mvn' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Comment: however.. this command DID work: C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.2.1\bin>mvn -version

Comment: @user3730244, add environment variable as in screenshot attached above

Comment: i created the following 2 variables:

Comment: MAVEN_HOME C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.2.1

Path C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.2.1\bin

Comment: found hte error - just needed to close my dos window and re-open

Answer (score 0):

This is a quite old tutorial, but you don't need to mvn3 just go to the project's folder where the pom.xml resides (in dos) and type:

```
mvn clean install
```

If everything is right it compiles and packages your code that you can find under the **target** folder

Comment: that didnt work got message: C:\ADT\workspace\firstmaven>mvn
'mvn' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: however.. this command DID work: C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.2.1\bin>mvn -version

Comment: Ahh your maven folder is not added to the path. So create an M2_HOME environment variable that points to  C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.2.1. Then add %M2_HOME%\bin to PATH.

Comment: I recommend to read "Installation instructions" section on this page: http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi
It helps you to setup maven properly on your machine!